# fastlane - Error cloning certificates repo

Tags: command-line-interface, bitbucket, git-clone, fastlane, fastlane-match

I am having some issues with fastlane and cloning a git repo from BitBucket. I am getting following error:

```
fatal: could not read Username for 'https://bitbucket.org': terminal prompts disabled
[17:21:34]: Exit status: 128
[17:21:34]: Error cloning certificates repo, please make sure you have read access to the repository you want to use
[17:21:34]: Run the following command manually to make sure you're properly authenticated:
```

I can manually `git clone` the repo without issue but when I am running it with fastlane, I am facing issues.

Answer (score 2):

This error means git can't find the username for the repo when run with terminal prompts disabled. You should be able to reproduce this by trying to clone the repo yourself like so:

```
$ GIT_TERMINAL_PROMPT=0 git clone https://bitbucket.org/org_name/repo_name
```

git is requiring you to enter the username manually because it does not have a credential stored.

Since you're using fastlane, I'm going to assume the most likely cause: you're on macOS but you haven't configured the `git-credential-osxkeychain` tool which provides credentials from the keychain to the `git` command line tool.

1. Run

   ```
   $ git credential-osxkeychain
   ```

   to verify the tool is installed.

   > If this fails, either install Xcode command line tools, or run `brew install git` to install it.
2. Run

   ```
   $ git config --global credential.helper osxkeychain
   ```

   to configure the tool.
3. Clone your repo (`git clone …`) as normal and login

Now your BitBucket credentials should be stored in your keychain and both `GIT_TERMINAL_PROMPT=0 git clone` and fastlane match should succeed.

If you're not on macOS, you'll need to install and configure a similar `credential.helper` for your operating system.

Comment: What if you have multiple users and gitconfig isn't working to redirect the  local user instead the global one?

Comment: You should still use `--global` even if you have multiple users. Global means all repos for this user; local means this repo only.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue and I have added githubkey path

```
match(git_private_key:"/Users/ajeetsharma/Desktop/Study/Fastlane/FastLaneDemo2/fastlane/gitHubKey")
```

And It has resolved